# Remove the \r\n\r\n rest of the place and before and after the specified tags ul, li

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to remove the `\r\n\r\n` if occurs in multiple time so it would be `\r\n\r\n` to `\r\n`.

After that if the `\r\n` or `\n` come next to the HTML `<li>` and `</li>` or `<ul></ul>` which showing in attached image.

```
var str= "\r\n\r\nSometimes, fast food or a meal at your favorite eatery is the easiest course of action.\r\n\r\nThat’s OK — just because you’re eating out doesn’t mean your food has to be unhealthy.<h2>Ways to Eat Healthier at Restaurants</h2>\r\n<ol>\r\n \t<li>\r\n<h3>Choose healthier food options.</h3>\r\n</li>\r\n</ol>\r\nMany restaurants have healthy food options on the menu. Head straight for that section and avoid anything that’s breaded, fried, crispy, or buttered. Instead of fries as your side dish, choose veggies, fruit, or a salad. If you get a salad, ask that dressing come on the side and use it sparingly. \r\n<ol start=\"2\">\r\n \t<li>\r\n<h3>Control your portions.</h3> \r\n</li>\r\n</ol>\r\nMany restaurants serve giant portions. Save half your meal for lunch the next day. If you don’t trust yourself, ask your server for a to-go container when placing your food order. When your meal arrives at the table, pack up half of it immediately.\r\n<ol start=\"3\">\r\n \t<li>\r\n<h3>Eat slowly.</h3>\r\n</li>\r\n</ol>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";

    str = str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '').replace(/[\t]+/g, '') ;
```

and

```
str = str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n').replace(/[\t]+/g, '') ;
```

The first case it is removing all the places \n and it is disturbing my UI.
Second, disturb the `<li>` and `</li>` UI

I wanted to achieve below

1. Sometimes str starts with the multiple `\r\n` and ends with the same
   so I want to remove all those.
2. Which come in between str `\r\n\r\n`
   wanted to keep them as single `\r\n`. for example - `course of action.\r\n\r\nThat’s OK — just because you`.
3. Then srt `<ol>\r\n \t<li>\r\n<h3>Choose healthier food options.</h3>\r\n</li>\r\n</ol>\r\n` (should become `<ol><li><h3>Choose healthier food options.</h3></li></ol>`) or any other specified tag should remove `\r\n`.

[image]

Comment: From what you write, you need `.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/g, '$1').replace(/\r?\n(<\/?(?:li|ul)\b[^>]*>)/gi, '$1')` or something similar.

Comment: Actually, your second sentence is not clear, what do you plan to do with linebreaks  "coming next to" `<li>` and `<ul>`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Edited my qustion

Comment: _...which showing in attached image._ There is no image attached :) Might help us to answer your question better

Comment: What do you mean by "come with"? Please post a very minimal string with expected output showing all these requirements.

Comment: For #1 use `str.trim()` which will remove all whitespace at beginning and end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I was playing with the more solution and forgot to update this. Now Updated with examples

Comment: What should `<ol>\r\n \t<li>\r\n<h3>Choose healthier food options.</h3>\r\n</li>\r\n</ol>\r\n` turn into? The first part is easy: `s.trim().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/g, '$1')`

Comment: <ol><li><h3>Choose healthier food options.</h3></li></ol>

Comment: Ok, so you do not only want to remove line breaks, you want to remove all whitespace there. Try `s.trim().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/g, '$1').replace(/\s*(<\/?(?:[ou]l|li)>)\s*/gi, '$1')`.

Comment: Yes because its killing my UI :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot for your suggestion just tested with my QA its working.

Comment: @MukeshS Good, I added an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.trim().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/g, '$1').replace(/\s*(<\/?(?:[ou]l|li)>)\s*/gi, '$1')
```

This does the following:

- `.trim()` - removes all whitespace from start/end of the string
- `.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/g, '$1')` - shrinks all repeated consecutive line breaks into single line breaks
- `.replace(/\s*(<\/?(?:[ou]l|li)>)\s*/gi, '$1')` - removes all whitespace from both ends of `<ul>`, `</ul>`, `<ol>`, `</ol>`, `<li>` and `</li>` even with attributes.